# Get product image url of specific store view with or without https

Tags: magento-1.8, product, store-view, product-images

1. i have to call an ajax request from an external website which (the
   simple way) returns the link to an product image of a store view i
   added to the request. The problem is, that the following function
   call always returns the path from the default store view, cause the
   request is to the default store.

   ```
   $this->helper('catalog/image')
       ->init($product, 'image')
       ->keepFrame(false)
       ->resize(250);
   ```

   2. If the calling site is a https site, the website can't show the image, because it's loaded from a non https site.

So there are two questions:

1. How can i load an image path of a specific store view id?
2. How can i load the image path with the secure base url?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way is to strip the protocol designator and turn it into a [Protocol Relative URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Protocol-relative_URLs):

```
// This assumes $product is from a collection that is constructed including a call to:
// Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection::setProductStoreId()
$url = $this->helper('catalog/image')
    ->init($product, 'image')
    ->keepFrame(false)
    ->resize(250);
$url = preg_replace('#^https?://#, '//', $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code first of all call helper of catalog

```
echo  Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail');
```

From this code you can get cache path also.

$item should be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product so you should be able to get the image url using the catalog image helper:

```
$imageUrl = (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'image');
```

So your code should look like this (only the section that should display the image)

```
<div class="image_product">
    <a href="<?php echo $item->getProductUrl(); ?>">
       <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'image')/*->resize(200, 200)*/; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->getName();?>" />
    </a>
</div>
```

If you want the image at a specific size, just uncomment the resize method and change the width and height.

Have you tried this?

```
Mage::getUrl('',array('_secure'=>true))
```

I think that gets you the base secure url, I believe.

Comment: That's exactly the way i tried before? So the function returns the image path with the base path of the defalt store view. I wanna have the image path with the basepath from a specific store view.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($products,'small_image')->resize(210); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, people are answering point 2 of your question but not point 1...

To get the path for a specific store view, you have to apply that store view id to the product *before loading it*. For example:

```
/**
 * some code to work out what $storeId and $productId are
**/
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->load($productId);
```

And then your code should work as desired.

If the product has been loaded already you can still use the above code to reload it (just use `$product->getId()` in place of `$productId` above).